# Adding difference columns to existing df

Tags: pandas, difference

My goal is to add columns that show differences between my previous columns

df

```
Name 0  1  2   
A    3  1  0
B    5  4  1
```

result:

```
Name 0  1  2  d1        d2 
A    3  1  0  2 (=3-1)  1 (=1-0)
B    5  4  1  1 (=5-4)  3 (=4-1)
```

I was thinking creating a new df to find compute the differences then add it back to the  original df, but it doesn't work out since it still requires using the original data.  Is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
difference = (df.shift(axis=1)-df).dropna(axis=1).add_prefix('d')
pd.concat([df,difference],axis=1)
```

- .shift(), shifts the index down so when you subtract the rows, they will do so in the proper order
- Subtract then recombine

Comment: Hey. You can actually shift horizontally. Things like `df2.shift(1, axis=1) `

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll update my answer when I have a moment.

Comment: @Tai I think that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Using `diff`:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
df[['d1','d2']] = -df.diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:]
```

```
df.reset_index()

Name  0  1  2   d1   d2
A     3  1  0  2.0  1.0
B     5  4  1  1.0  3.0
```

Comment: Very neat! But I think you're missing a line of code or two. Although I think I know what it is you've done.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep, reset it back :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can also select the columns first with column names. Finally do substraction.

```
df[['d1','d2']] = df[["0", "1"]] - df[["1", "2"]].values

    Name 0  1   2   d1  d2
    A   3   1   0   2   1
    B   5   4   1   1   3
```

(We need `.values` to only extract values and ignore its column name. You can try to it without `.values`.)